# css selector using Cheerio exclusion of double class

Tags: html, css, dom, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I have a rather "weird" scenario (web scraping). I want to select `class=g` only but **not** those with `class="g g"` (double class `g`). How to do that in jQuery?

If I use $('.g'), it will select both `.g` and `.g .g`

**UPDATE 1:**

If you don't think `.g .g` is valid, do View Source in Google search results ;)

Comment: I don't think `class="g g"` is valid HTML...

Comment: What does `$(".g:not(.g.g)")` do?

Comment: `$(".g:not(.g.g)")` doesn't select anything.

Comment: I didn't find any `.g.g` on a random results page.

Comment: @JanDvorak maybe Google pops that out randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the following scenario where you have two Div tag with above classes

```
<div class="g"></div>

<div class="g g"></div>
```

Write following to get only those div which have class"g"

```
alert($("div[class='g']").length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Even if I don't think `g g` is valid (Let me check it)..and therefore `$(".g:not(.g.g)")` wouldn't work, you could do something like:

```
var myWeirdElements = $('.g').map(function(){return this.className.indexOf('g g') && this ;});

// or, as mentioned on the comment, using Array.filter method
```

demo => http://jsfiddle.net/GeAaA/

Edit: about the 2nd comment, you just have to count how many g (simple regex)

Comment: If OP asked that element shouldn't have multiple `g` classes & any element has `<div class="g n g"></div>` how can we handle that ?

Comment: @stecb I forgot to mention, I am not "really" using jQuery. It's Cheerio on node.js so this.className doesn't exists. Any good replacement of that?

Comment: @HP. you definitely should have mentioned that.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yah I thought Cheerio is a rip and replace of jQuery on node but I was wrong. The objects are not the same in many cases...

Comment: @HP "How to do that in jQuery?" .. btw this.className is not jQuery is simple plain DOM

Comment: My mistake, it's `indexOf` then --> `TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: @HP weird.. http://matthewmueller.github.com/cheerio/ check `.map` ...it should work properly...

Comment: yah its strange. Dunno... :|

Comment: @HP try to log `this` inside the map callback

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution to other answers, you can use SerpApi's [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api). This API makes it possible to forget about figuring out how to extract something from the page, bypass blocks from search engines, and maintain the code (parser) over time.

All you need is to iterate over the structured JSON and get the data you want. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=Coffee&gl=us&hl=en).

**Usage example ([also, check it in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-search-SerpApi-example#index.js)):**

```js
const SerpApi = require('google-search-results-nodejs');
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY);     //your api key from serpapi.com

const params = {
  engine: "google",                         // search engine
  q: "Coffee",                              // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",              // google domain of the search
  gl: "us",                                 // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                                 // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
};

const callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

// Show result as JSON
search.json(params, callback);
```

**Output:**

```json
{
   "recipes_results":[
      {
         "title":"Coffee recipes",
         "link":"https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/coffee-recipes",
         "source":"BBC Good Food",
         "ingredients":[
            "Instant coffee"
         ],
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/b50a38f136c7abe67e61eef25884f35798c0551f1d43ace6237f6830200fa235.jpeg"
      },
      {
         "title":"20 Great Coffee Drinks From Around the World",
         "link":"https://insanelygoodrecipes.com/coffee-recipes/",
         "source":"Insanely Good Recipes",
         "rating":4.5,
         "reviews":8,
         "ingredients":[
            "Turkish coffee",
            "vietnamese coffee",
            "white chocolate mocha",
            "cold brew coffee",
            "frappuccino"
         ],
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/b50a38f136c7abe67e61eef25884f357aa875ca61585258439c617a0846d590a.jpeg"
      },
      {
         "title":"Dalgona Coffee",
         "link":"https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/a32072159/dalgona-coffee-recipe/",
         "source":"Delish.com",
         "rating":3.8,
         "reviews":42,
         "total_time":"10 min",
         "ingredients":[
            "Instant coffee",
            "ice",
            "milk"
         ],
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/b50a38f136c7abe67e61eef25884f357b2162e9f1c396805c73a0850d499fd01.jpeg"
      }
   ],
   "local_map":{
      "link":"https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&q=Coffee&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rldoc=1&rllag=37769342,-122389993,242&tbm=lcl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFz_LLo9X4AhUwGlkFHeVCB84QtgN6BAgXEAE",
      "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/57f06389eb0c57c24320522b45952370.png",
      "gps_coordinates":{
         "latitude":37.769342,
         "longitude":-122.389993,
         "altitude":242
      }
   },
   "local_results":{
      "more_locations_link":"https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&q=Coffee&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFz_LLo9X4AhUwGlkFHeVCB84QjGp6BAgWEAI",
      "places":[
         {
            "position":1,
            "title":"Philz Coffee",
            "place_id":"14850561974798048043",
            "lsig":"AB86z5V2CpkHAoUti4UAfsYs_iF5",
            "place_id_search":"https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&lsig=AB86z5V2CpkHAoUti4UAfsYs_iF5&ludocid=14850561974798048043&q=Coffee&tbm=lcl",
            "description":"Dine-in·Takeout·Delivery",
            "rating":4.5,
            "type":"Philz Coffee",
            "hours":"San Francisco, CA · In Chase Center",
            "address":"4.5(21) · $$ · Coffee shop",
            "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/db978ef22623ebbaba5a259d7610a82f1e67d73393884509c7d902e95abeda94a9e2ac25fedcf5ad.jpeg"
         }, ... other results
      ]
   },
   "organic_results":[
      {
         "position":1,
         "title":"Coffee - Wikipedia",
         "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee",
         "displayed_link":"https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Coffee",
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/0293bd7aa87e25161235b6fe723a6c2dae65c3f9f164074026df984d8f3e5820.jpeg",
         "snippet":"Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain flowering plants in the Coffea genus. From the coffee fruit, ...",
         "snippet_highlighted_words":[
            "Coffee",
            "coffee",
            "coffee"
         ],
         "sitelinks":{
            "inline":[
               {
                  "title":"Coffee bean",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_bean"
               },
               {
                  "title":"History",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_coffee"
               },
               {
                  "title":"Coffee preparation",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_preparation"
               },
               {
                  "title":"Coffee production",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_production"
               }
            ]
         },
         "rich_snippet":{
            "bottom":{
               "extensions":[
                  "Region of origin: Horn of Africa and ‎South Ara...‎",
                  "Color: Black, dark brown, light brown, beige",
                  "Introduced: 15th century"
               ],
               "detected_extensions":{
                  "introduced_th_century":15
               }
            }
         },
         "about_this_result":{
            "source":{
               "description":"Wikipedia is a multilingual free online encyclopedia written and maintained by a community of volunteers through open collaboration and a wiki-based editing system. Individual contributors, also called editors, are known as Wikipedians. Wikipedia is the largest and most-read reference work in history.",
               "icon":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/0293bd7aa87e25161235b6fe723a6c2d8021773b9a274d74b2c9d60da12b643d997acd2685004b3a989713a5bd03429c.png"
            },
            "keywords":[
               "coffee"
            ],
            "languages":[
               "English"
            ],
            "regions":[
               "the United States"
            ]
         },
         "about_page_link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=About+https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee&tbm=ilp&ilps=ADNMCi0tVhSB-fGHOJYgrIxB0xlXYrPGPA",
         "cached_page_link":"https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:U6oJMnF-eeUJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us",
         "related_pages_link":"https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+Coffee"
      }, ... other results
   ],
   ... and other search results
}
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApiAs an alternative solution to other answers, you can use SerpApi's [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api). This API makes it possible to forget about figuring out how to extract something from the page, bypass blocks from search engines, and maintain the code (parser) over time.

All you need is to iterate over the structured JSON and get the data you want. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=Coffee&gl=us&hl=en).

**Usage example ([also, check it in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-search-SerpApi-example#index.js)):**

```js
const SerpApi = require('google-search-results-nodejs');
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY);     //your api key from serpapi.com

const params = {
  engine: "google",                         // search engine
  q: "Coffee",                              // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",              // google domain of the search
  gl: "us",                                 // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                                 // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
};

const callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

// Show result as JSON
search.json(params, callback);
```

**Output:**

```json
{
   "recipes_results":[
      {
         "title":"Coffee recipes",
         "link":"https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/coffee-recipes",
         "source":"BBC Good Food",
         "ingredients":[
            "Instant coffee"
         ],
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/b50a38f136c7abe67e61eef25884f35798c0551f1d43ace6237f6830200fa235.jpeg"
      },
      {
         "title":"20 Great Coffee Drinks From Around the World",
         "link":"https://insanelygoodrecipes.com/coffee-recipes/",
         "source":"Insanely Good Recipes",
         "rating":4.5,
         "reviews":8,
         "ingredients":[
            "Turkish coffee",
            "vietnamese coffee",
            "white chocolate mocha",
            "cold brew coffee",
            "frappuccino"
         ],
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/b50a38f136c7abe67e61eef25884f357aa875ca61585258439c617a0846d590a.jpeg"
      },
      {
         "title":"Dalgona Coffee",
         "link":"https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/a32072159/dalgona-coffee-recipe/",
         "source":"Delish.com",
         "rating":3.8,
         "reviews":42,
         "total_time":"10 min",
         "ingredients":[
            "Instant coffee",
            "ice",
            "milk"
         ],
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/b50a38f136c7abe67e61eef25884f357b2162e9f1c396805c73a0850d499fd01.jpeg"
      }
   ],
   "local_map":{
      "link":"https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&q=Coffee&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rldoc=1&rllag=37769342,-122389993,242&tbm=lcl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFz_LLo9X4AhUwGlkFHeVCB84QtgN6BAgXEAE",
      "image":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/57f06389eb0c57c24320522b45952370.png",
      "gps_coordinates":{
         "latitude":37.769342,
         "longitude":-122.389993,
         "altitude":242
      }
   },
   "local_results":{
      "more_locations_link":"https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&q=Coffee&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFz_LLo9X4AhUwGlkFHeVCB84QjGp6BAgWEAI",
      "places":[
         {
            "position":1,
            "title":"Philz Coffee",
            "place_id":"14850561974798048043",
            "lsig":"AB86z5V2CpkHAoUti4UAfsYs_iF5",
            "place_id_search":"https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&lsig=AB86z5V2CpkHAoUti4UAfsYs_iF5&ludocid=14850561974798048043&q=Coffee&tbm=lcl",
            "description":"Dine-in·Takeout·Delivery",
            "rating":4.5,
            "type":"Philz Coffee",
            "hours":"San Francisco, CA · In Chase Center",
            "address":"4.5(21) · $$ · Coffee shop",
            "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/db978ef22623ebbaba5a259d7610a82f1e67d73393884509c7d902e95abeda94a9e2ac25fedcf5ad.jpeg"
         }, ... other results
      ]
   },
   "organic_results":[
      {
         "position":1,
         "title":"Coffee - Wikipedia",
         "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee",
         "displayed_link":"https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Coffee",
         "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/0293bd7aa87e25161235b6fe723a6c2dae65c3f9f164074026df984d8f3e5820.jpeg",
         "snippet":"Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain flowering plants in the Coffea genus. From the coffee fruit, ...",
         "snippet_highlighted_words":[
            "Coffee",
            "coffee",
            "coffee"
         ],
         "sitelinks":{
            "inline":[
               {
                  "title":"Coffee bean",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_bean"
               },
               {
                  "title":"History",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_coffee"
               },
               {
                  "title":"Coffee preparation",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_preparation"
               },
               {
                  "title":"Coffee production",
                  "link":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_production"
               }
            ]
         },
         "rich_snippet":{
            "bottom":{
               "extensions":[
                  "Region of origin: Horn of Africa and ‎South Ara...‎",
                  "Color: Black, dark brown, light brown, beige",
                  "Introduced: 15th century"
               ],
               "detected_extensions":{
                  "introduced_th_century":15
               }
            }
         },
         "about_this_result":{
            "source":{
               "description":"Wikipedia is a multilingual free online encyclopedia written and maintained by a community of volunteers through open collaboration and a wiki-based editing system. Individual contributors, also called editors, are known as Wikipedians. Wikipedia is the largest and most-read reference work in history.",
               "icon":"https://serpapi.com/searches/62bda4a2f0adfb0a9364cfb4/images/0293bd7aa87e25161235b6fe723a6c2d8021773b9a274d74b2c9d60da12b643d997acd2685004b3a989713a5bd03429c.png"
            },
            "keywords":[
               "coffee"
            ],
            "languages":[
               "English"
            ],
            "regions":[
               "the United States"
            ]
         },
         "about_page_link":"https://www.google.com/search?q=About+https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee&tbm=ilp&ilps=ADNMCi0tVhSB-fGHOJYgrIxB0xlXYrPGPA",
         "cached_page_link":"https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:U6oJMnF-eeUJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us",
         "related_pages_link":"https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+Coffee"
      }, ... other results
   ],
   ... and other search results
}
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi